# How to find funds with long history to use in backtest?

Tags: backtesting, historical-data, etf, mutual-fund

Is there a way (website/code) to find funds/etfs for a given asset class and how much data history is available (yahoo finance or other) ? It could be as simple as a list of funds by asset class and their data start date.

Comment: Watch out! If you are backtesting a trading strategy, selecting a universe of funds with long histories gives you major look-ahead biases.

Comment: What do you mean by funds?  Closed-end funds?  Non-exchange-traded Mutual Funds?  ETFs?  ETNs?  Delisted variants?

Answer (score 2):

yahoo finance has a large set of historical data. it's available for free. There are a few libraries, to retrieve the data

Comment: Survivorship bias is present in that data set.    How much missing?  Almost 500 delisted ETFs, almost 100 delisted ETNs and over 450 delisted CEFs.

Answer (score 0):

quant tick downloader. free with the most accurate free tick data u can find.

click [here](http://www.strategyquant.com/tickdownloader/)

also for yahoo finance data in R try the Quantmod package

```
getSymbols("^GSPC", from="1990-01-01" , to ="2000-01-01" )
```

Comment: But how would you quickly find how much history is available?

Comment: extract data + `nrows()`